# Ideal BMI / Body & Vicelar fat for my body measurements

Tags: body-fat

I am 43 years , Height 166 Cms , Weight 75.8 Kg , BMI 27.5 , Body fat 32.8% , Viscelar Fat 10% , what would be ideal measurements for me.

What steps / action to be taken to attain fitness.

Comment: This question is way to broad to get a good answer. Can you specify goals? The term "fit" can mean a lot of different things to a lot of different people. Also, BMI isn't the greatest tool to measure fitness.

Comment: Better foget about BMI, yep https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/bmi-is-a-terrible-measure-of-health/

Comment: And also, weight and fat percentage sure would be in dependency, so, my advise - try to low your fat level to 10-12%.

Comment: BMI/body fat also depend on gender. Females tend to have higher body fat

Answer (score 4):

What your ideal measurements would be is something noone here can easily answer because, firstly forget BMI as it's very inaccurate and doesnt consider a lot of important factors. And it depends and what your goal is. Do you want to be very muscular, or very thin or something in between?

And on the matter of losing weight and getting fit, my personal advice would not be to go running, or going to the gym or something like this, because lets be honest, for 80% of people its a not fun and a chore and will loose interest and motivation in 1-2 months.

What worked for me (i was a little bit chubby too last year) is to find a sport you genuinly like. For me this was bouldering. But i believe if you try out some stuff everyone can find some activity which he likes. And when you have found it, do it regularly! 2-3 times a week~.

Then look at your diet. I really dont like "diets". What matters is a livestyle change  into a healthy direction. Eat more veggys, less meat, less carbs. If you eat healthy most of the time, even sometimes a treat is perfectly oke :)

This might take some months, depending on your body and genetics of course, but if you do this i can garantuee! you that you will see and feel change, and its a healthy way without yojo effect :)

Comment: Pretty solid advice. Doing something you enjoy while working on your general health is good. Also, take of your jacket.

Comment: @mjb what do you mean with take off your jacket?

Comment: Because the thing goes skkrraa.

Comment: @MJB HAHAHAHAHA!