# Loose fat, gain muscle simultaneously

Tags: weight-loss, workout-routines, diet, muscle-gain, timing

I'm a 28 year old man having done weight training on & off for last 5 years, having height 5'11", waist 38" and weight 95 KGs. My goal is to **gain muscle and loose fat simultaneously** over a long period of time, without going through bulking and cutting cycles, to have a well built and defined body. What are the workout and food intake/timing requirements to achieve that goal?

Comment: I reccoment that you edit your question and state what you actually want to achieve. Is it just fitness or do you want to get ripped and or bulky? I will alter my answer accordingly :)

Comment: Context please. Who are you? A pro bodybuilder on juice? A 500 pound man that lives in his bed? A 90 year old woman with liver cancer? A 16 year old teen that has never seen a gym? A slightly overweight guy in a mid life crisis ?

Comment: Required info added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***TLDR***: Do heavy compound exercises combined with relatively high rep isolation exercises while on a high protein diet.

**I would suggest doing heavy compound movements** like deadlifting, squatting and bench pressing. Preferably doing sets of no more than 5 reps. You can even build up to 1-3 reps on extra heavy sets.

Add isolation exercises to each muscle group and do higher reps on these, 8 to 12 reps per set. You could also add some cardio but this isn't necessary so if you enjoy cardio go for it, if you don't, don't.

**As for food**, I would suggest finding out what ammount of calories you need to maintain what you already have. I'd go for a diet high in protein to build muscle. If you eat to many carbs you might find it hard to lose the excess fat, even though that is very personal (I personally don't gain fat on a high carb diet but I know a lot of people that do).

Comment: Very logical advice. How many calories should I go above my maintenance calories to achieve my goal, ie loose Fat gain Muscle?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at my answer from a couple of weeks ago: [Ideal BMI / Body & Vicelar fat for my body measurements](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/36951/ideal-bmi-body-vicelar-fat-for-my-body-measurements/36952#36952)

To recap in my opinion you need to find something where you have fun and do that regularly a few times a week. And imho there is no need for a strict "diet" because if you change your livestyle to a more healthy one with less meat, less carbs, more veggys you will become thinner and thinner. And if you do your sports (something where you have to move like bouldering, not golfing) regularly you WILL build muscle.

You wont become ripped a.f. because this will need a very strict diet and lots and lots and lots of training, but for a fit healthy and toned body regular activity and healthy eating will do the trick in the long run :)